# JUnit Test Suite and Ant Build "ClassNotFoundException"

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, junit

I am using Eclipse Indigo. Not sure what is going on, but what I try to invoke the test suite from an ant build I get a ClassNotFoundException. However, if I right click on the JUnit Test class and run as Junit Test, it runs the tests fine. The error says that the file ./test/_ObservableSortUnitTests is not found. It gives the same error even if I give a full path to the file.

Here is my error:

```
Buildfile: /home/jason/Dev/ObservableSort/build.xml
Compile:
Test:
    [junit] Testsuite: ./test/_ObservableSortUnitTests
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
    [junit]     Caused an ERROR
    [junit] ./test/_ObservableSortUnitTests
    [junit] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ./test/_ObservableSortUnitTests
    [junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    [junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    [junit]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
    [junit]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:424)
    [junit]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:138)

BUILD FAILED
/home/jason/Dev/ObservableSort/build.xml:75: Test ./test/_ObservableSortUnitTests failed

Total time: 1 second
```

Here is my ant script (disclaimer: I am very new to ant):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project default="Build" name="CS 151 Project Build Script" >
    <!--ANT 1.7 is required  -->
    <property name="home" value="." />                
    <property name="src.dir" value = "${home}/src" />
    <property name="dest.dir" value="${home}/Release" />
    <property name="dir.build" value="${home}/lib" />
    <property name="dir.javadoc" value="${dest.dir}/Javadoc" />
    <property name="dir.classes" value="${dest.dir}/Classes" />
    <property name="dir.junit.reports" value="${dest.dir}/Reports" />
    <property name="test.suite.dir" value="${home}/test" />
    <property name="test.suite.class" value ="${test.suite.dir}/_ObservableSortUnitTests" />

    <path id="build.class.path">
        <fileset dir="${dir.build}">
            <include name="*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path> 

    <path id="test.class.path">
        <pathelement location="${junit.test.suite}" />
    </path>

    <target name="Clean" description="Deletes all old files">
        <delete dir="${dir.javadoc}" />
        <delete dir="${dir.classes}" />
        <delete dir="${dir.junit.reports}" />
    </target>

    <target name="Prepare" description="Creates all necessary directories">
        <mkdir dir="${dir.javadoc}" />
        <mkdir dir="${dir.classes}" />
        <mkdir dir="${dir.junit.reports}" />
    </target>   

    <target name="Compile">
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${dir.classes}" includeantruntime="true">
            <classpath refid="build.class.path" />
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="Full" description="Executes all build targets">
        <antcall target="Clean" />
        <antcall target="Prepare" />
        <antcall target="Compile" />
        <antcall target="Test" />
        <antcall target="Build" />
        <antcall target="Javadoc" />
        <antcall target="run" />
    </target>

    <target name="Build" description="Creates executable jar" depends="Clean, Prepare, Compile">
        <jar destfile="${dest.dir}/ObservableSort.jar" filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="cs151.project1.ObservableSortTest"/>
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="."/>
            </manifest>
            <fileset dir="${home}/bin"/>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="Run" depends="Compile, Build">
        <java jar="${dest.dir}/ObservableSort.jar" fork="true" />
    </target>           

    <target name="Run with Unit Tests" depends="Compile, Build, Test">
        <java jar="${dest.dir}/ObservableSort.jar" fork="true" />
    </target>

    <target name="Javadoc" description="Generate Javadoc" depends="Compile" >
        <javadoc access="public" author="true"  destdir="${dir.javadoc}" nodeprecated="false" nodeprecatedlist="false" noindex="false" nonavbar="false" notree="false" packagenames="cs151.project1.sorters.insertionsort,cs151.project1.sorters.selectionsort,cs151.project1.Quantifiable,cs151.project1,cs151.project1.sorters.quicksort,cs151.project1.views" source="1.6" sourcepath="${src.dir}" splitindex="false" use="true" version="true"/>
    </target>

    <target name="Test" depends="Compile">
        <junit>
            <classpath refid="build.class.path" />
            <classpath refid="test.class.path" />
            <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" />
            <test name="${test.suite.class}" haltonerror="true" />
        </junit>
    </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake: The JUnit classes were not yet compiled.

Solution:

- Compile the project into a directory X
- Compile the JUnit classes into a directory Y
- Add the JUnit jar to directory Z

Inside the < test > tag, add directories X, Y, and Z to the classpath.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the path to the testsuite class instead of the fully qualified name of the class.

Even though java classes are *stored* in filesystem folders, Java requires you to specify the package name dotted, not slashed.

Most likely the correct classname is `test._ObservableSortUnitTests` or maybe `_ObservableSortUnitTests`

Comment: I've tried several different permutations of classpath and filename that I think would be correct but it just doesn't seem to like me.

Comment: I have the TestSuite class defined ${home}/test and it is contained within (default package). Any suggestions of what to try next?

Comment: If your test is in the `${home}/test` folder, then you should add that to the classpath of the Test target. If the TestSuite is in the default package, then you should only specify the classname `_ObservableSortUnitTests`

Answer (score 2):

If you specify the name of the test class in the junit task, then you need to use the fully qualifed class name, as Mark says. From [JUnit task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html)

```
<junit>
  <test name="my.test.TestCase"/>
</junit>
```

If, however, you're using a batchtest, you can specify file names, but you need to add the .java on the end:

```
  <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${reports.tests}">
    <fileset dir="${src.tests}">
      <include name="**/*Test*.java"/>
      <exclude name="**/AllTests.java"/>
    </fileset>
  </batchtest>
```

Comment: It is a TestSuite class. I have the TestSuite class defined ${home}/test and it is contained within (default package). I have tried as many different possible combinations that I would think are correct and none work. Any suggestions of what to try next?